# Xamarin-iOS today widget, unable to load issue

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm making today widget extension, where I get symbols of coins and then I am making web request to get objects.

In every reload, widget is drawing view again and calling WidgetPerformUpdate method, from 1/10 widget show's me unable to load.

I debuged app and issue is coming at me when I'm adding some objects into widget.

I've stacked in this problem about 1 week, I've read all today widget documentation,tutorials there is no help from nowhere.

I don't know what to do, unable to load is my nightmare.

There is my TodawyWidgetViewController code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NotificationCenter;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using CryptoCurrencyPCL.POCO;
using CryptoCurrencyPCL.Middleware;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CryptoCurrencyPCL.Extensions;
using CryptoCurrencyPCL.Enums;
using CoreGraphics;
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using CryptoPCL.POCO;

namespace CryptoTodayWidget
{
    public partial class TodayViewController : UIViewController, INCWidgetProviding,IUITableViewDataSource,IUITableViewDelegate
    {
        NSUserDefaults userDefaults;
        const string ReuseId = "currencyCellReuseId";
        List<CoinDetail> _coins;
        List<CoinDetail> _cachedCoins;
        List<FavoriteCoin> _favorites;
        List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
        Currency itemCurrency;
        private CGSize _maxSize;
        private string nsStringForValues;
        private string nsString;
        private List<string> deserializedObjectsSymbols;
        bool _firstInit = true;


        protected TodayViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ReuseId, indexPath) as WidgetCell;

            var item = _coins[indexPath.Row];
            var favorite = _favorites[indexPath.Row];

            cell.InitData(item,favorite,itemCurrency);

            return cell;
        }

        public nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return _coins?.Count ?? 0;
        }

        [Export("tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 50;
        }

        [Export("numberOfSectionsInTableView:")]
        public nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public async override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var webClient = CryptoCurrencyPCL.Services.CryptoWebClient.Instance;
            tableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

            _cachedCoins = _coins;
            if(_coins != null) {
                initTableView();
            }

            ExtensionContext.SetWidgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode(NCWidgetDisplayMode.Expanded);
        }

        private void initTableView()
        {
            tableView.DataSource = this;
            tableView.Delegate = this;
            tableView.AllowsSelection = false;
            tableView.ReloadData();
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        }

        [Export("widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:")]
        public async void WidgetPerformUpdate(Action<NCUpdateResult> completionHandler)
        {
            var webClient = CryptoCurrencyPCL.Services.CryptoWebClient.Instance;



            try
            {
                initLoading();
                bool check = false;
                userDefaults = new NSUserDefaults("group.com.mpdc.todayextension", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
                nsStringForValues = userDefaults?.StringForKey(new NSString("MyAppsValues"));
                nsString = userDefaults?.StringForKey("currencyKey");
                itemCurrency = (Currency)Enum.Parse(typeof(Currency), nsString);

                _favorites = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FavoriteCoin>>(nsStringForValues);

                deserializedObjectsSymbols = _favorites.Select(o => o.FavoriteCoinSymbol).ToList();


                _coins = await webClient.GetMultiCoinDetailsAsync(deserializedObjectsSymbols, itemCurrency); 


                if (ExtensionContext.GetWidgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode() == NCWidgetDisplayMode.Compact)
                {

                    this.PreferredContentSize =_maxSize;
                }

                else
                {
                    this.PreferredContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0, _coins.Count * 50);
                }

                initTableView();
                initLoading(false);

                tableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;

                completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                initLoading(false);
                completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.Failed);
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }


        void initLoading(bool visible = true)
        {

            if (visible)
            {
                ActivityIndicator.Hidden = false;
                ActivityIndicator.StartAnimating();
                return;
            }

            ActivityIndicator.Hidden = true;
            ActivityIndicator.StopAnimating();
        }

        [Export("widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:withMaximumSize:")]
        public void WidgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(NCWidgetDisplayMode activeDisplayMode, CoreGraphics.CGSize maxSize)
        {
            _maxSize = maxSize;

            if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.Compact)
            {

                this.PreferredContentSize = _maxSize;
            }

            else
            {
                if(_coins!=null)
                this.PreferredContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0, _coins.Count * 50);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can post the crash code to see the problem. Maybe it's the problem of "CryptoCurrencyPCL" or it takes too long to load data. Because the Today extension should not be used for a lengthy task.

Comment: Very strange problem is that its workin on simulator but not at real device

Comment: there's some difference between simulator and real device. Maybe you have too much data, try to reduce your datasouce and debug again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

It was working on simulator but not on the device.

The problem was happening when I was running my application on the device in debug mode.

I think with debug mode, there were happening memory issues.

I've run it in release mode and everything is working.